# Insert is only doing the first row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query that is returning some results from my database, it returns 4 rows, but when I do the insert it's only doing the first row and then stopping, does not seem to be doing an insert for each row that is returned from the first query.

```
$sql = "SELECT t.ID AS 'TopicID', t.seminar_id AS 'SeminarID', rl.resourceid AS 'ResourceID', r.ResourceType AS 'ResourceType'
        FROM topic t
        LEFT JOIN resourcelink rl ON rl.entityid = t.ID
        LEFT JOIN resources r ON r.ResourceID = rl.resourceid
        WHERE t.seminar_id = '124840'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($sql);
// echo "</pre>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $resourceID = $row['ResourceID'];
    $resourceType = $row['ResourceType'];

    if ($resourceID != '' && $resourceType != 1)
    {
        $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO resourcelink (resourceid, entityid, entitytype, linkorder, viewinplayer)
                VALUES ($resourceID, $topicID, 1, 0, 0)";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_insert);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to display the data you could issue an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` and spare the additional round trip.

Comment: Why don't you put `AND r1.resourceid != '' AND r.resourceType != 1` to the query, instead of doing them in the second loop?

Comment: You should stop using the obsolete `mysql` extension. It was deprecated years ago, and removed entirely in PHP 7.0. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` now.

Comment: Add error checking to see why it's failing. Put `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of the `mysql_query($sql_insert)` line.

Comment: Be careful what variable names you are using. You are altering $result in your while loop, so rename it to something boring like $result_1 or the like. Plus, you are not even using it, so you need to rethink things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're overwriting the `$result` variable when you do the first insert. So when the next iteration of the `while` loop calls `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`, it's fetching the result of the `INSERT`, not the result of the `SELECT`.

Since you never do anything with the result of the `INSERT`, there's no need to assign a variable. If you do need to use the result, you should use a different variable name. So change:

```
        $result = mysql_query($sql_insert);
```

to

```
        mysql_query($sql_insert) or die("Insert error: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: You'd leak the same information if you used `echo mysql_error();`. The leakage comes from displaying the SQL error, not dying. This is mainly for debugging, you should be more careful in production.